# Raspberry pi 3 UART non functional after configuring uart pins as GPIO

Tags: python, uart, gpio

I'm using python on a Raspberry Pi to test an external device.

The external device requires that the UART Tx line be low during initialization.  To accomplish this I configure the UART Tx line as a GPIO output during initialization:

```
GPIO.setup(14, GPIO.OUT)  
GPIO.output(14, GPIO.LOW)
```

At a later time, I configure the UART:

```
serial.Serial(port="/dev/serial0", baudrate=115200)
```

However, once the port has been configured as a GPIO, the UART does *not* work (no characters are transmitted) unless the Raspberry Pi is rebooted.
The UART works fine when the GPIO is NOT configured.
Adding GPIO.cleanup() has no effect.
Is there a way to programatically *undo* the GPIO configuration?

Comment: You're probably going at this incorrectly (i.e. mucking with pin control after RPi system initialization).  If you need the TxD line to be *"low during initialization"* of the external device, then outputting *space* instead of *mark* would accomplish that.  I.E. send a BREAK condition

Comment: You better be sure that this external device is referring to TTL levels rather than RS-232 levels when you claim that *"the external device requires that the UART Tx line be low during initialization'*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the GPIO back into UART mode, which happens to be mode ALT0 for GPIO 14 and 15.

The pigpio Python module uses the [set_mode](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#set_mode) function to set the mode, e.g. set_mode(14, pigpio.ALT0).

The pigpio pigs module uses the [mode](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#M/MODES) command, e.g. pigs m 14 0.